# Selected value to subReport

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I have a drop down list in the main report, I need sending a subreport, and get the selected value as parameter to this subreport.

In the subReport  Properties I have the name of parameter, but how can I specify the selected value from the drop down?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Value field in the dialog you show, enter an expression (fx button):

```
=Parameters!MyParameterName.Value
```

Comment: The problem with this expression is always is sendig the same parameter, not the selected value from my drop down list...

Comment: This should always send the selected value to the subreport. I use this format regularly without problems. Is your parameter a multi-value parameter? That could be the problem, in which case, you need to determine which of the multi-values to send to the subreport. Try putting a Textbox in your parent report with this expression and see what is set there. (Another possibility: Maybe you have multiple similar parameters, or maybe the values are the same for your parameter but the labels are different?)

Comment: The list of possible parameters is numbers from 1 to 93